# Enum.TryParse strange behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Why does this test pass? TestEnum doesn't contain and option with value "5". So this test should fail, but it doesn't.

```
        private enum TestEnum
        {
            FirstOption = 2,
            SecontOption = 3
        }

        [Test]
        public void EnumTryParseIntValue()
        {
            TestEnum enumValue;

            bool result = Enum.TryParse<TestEnum>(5.ToString(), out enumValue);

            Assert.IsTrue(result);
        }
```

Comment: Seems that the enum is flagged. 5 = 3+2 ... but i cant see any [Flags] attribute

Comment: Maybe read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx): " If *value* is the string representation of an integer that does not represent an underlying value of the *TEnum* enumeration, the method returns an enumeration member whose underlying value is *value* converted to an integral type" (and note that this is also consistent with e.g. casting `int`s to enums - the value doesn't have to be a defined one)

Comment: @S.L.: Flags wouldn't mean that there'd be a 5 value... flags involves bitwise OR-ing, not addition.

Comment: @JonSkeet it is too early in the morning ... didnt notice that. Thanks for the advice

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for your help. maybe I'll read it:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Enum.TryParse Method (String, TEnum)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If value is a name that does not correspond to a named constant of
>   TEnum, the method returns false. If value is the string representation
>   of an integer that does not represent an underlying value of the TEnum
>   enumeration, the method returns an enumeration member whose underlying
>   value is value converted to an integral type. If this behavior is
>   undesirable, call the IsDefined method to ensure that a particular
>   string representation of an integer is actually a member of TEnum.

"Returns an enumeration member whose underlying value is value converted to an integral type"
If the value is not present you get back the integer.  I don't consider getting back 5 to be an "enumeration member" but that is how it works. If you parse 2 you get FirstOption.

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TestEnum), 5.ToString()))
{
    result = Enum.TryParse<TestEnum>(5.ToString(), out enumValue);
    Debug.WriteLine(result);
    if (result)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(enumValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Enum.IsDefined(Type enumType,Object value) - Returns an indication whether a constant with a specified value exists in a specified enumeration.

[MSDN: Enum.IsDefined Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx)